# How to prevent the colored border over all dialogs after resuming from sleep?

Tags: 16.04, graphics, suspend, visual-artifacts, resume

About a week and a half ago, I updated/upgraded my 16.04 using `sudo apt upgrade`.

Since then, every time the laptop resumes from sleep, I get a strange border around **all** popup dialogs.

Any idea how to prevent it?

I tried updating/upgrading again but the problem continues.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a **partial** solution to remove the border. Running `pkill compiz` removed the border.

Why **partial** solution?

1. `pkill compiz` doesn't behave nicely with workspaces. It puts all windows of all workspaces into the first workspace :(
2. The problem reproduces after next resume from sleep, thus need to run `pkill compiz` after every resume from sleep.